# Specify ID/Name by annotation Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, data-annotations, meta-tags

Is it possible to specify the name/id fields by data annotations using Razor?

I have two partial views (create/edit) that come up in the same page, each with a separate view model but with identical properties names.

```
[Display(Prompt = "Live", Name = "Live")]
public bool Live { get; set; }
```

I'm trying to render a checkbox with a label for:

```
<div class="editor-field">
         @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Live})
         @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.Live, new {@class="checkbox-label" })
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Live)
 </div>
```

Which gets rendered too:

```
<div class="editor-field">
     <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Live field is required." id="Live" name="Live" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="Live" type="hidden" value="false">
     <label class="checkbox-label" for="Live">Live</label>
     <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Live" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

The above code is repeated once for the create partial view, and once for the edit partial view.

The user clicks buttons which makes those partial views come into view without reloading the page.

However once the first partial view has been rendered the second label for does not work - as the browser has already assigned an id for the first checkbox and the label can no longer point to it.

Ideally I'd like to be able to annotate the view models such that the rendered HTML would use an id/name specified.

```
[Display(Prompt = "Live", Name = "Live", id="createLive")]
    public bool Live { get; set; }

[Display(Prompt = "Live", Name = "Live", id="editLive")]
    public bool Live { get; set; }
```

and that these new id's would then be automatically picked up by the labelfor, and the the validationmessagefor

Is something like this possible?

Renaming the properties for each view model is an option... but it breaks some of the auto mapping I have working on the server side/would be less tidy IMO.

Comment: Why have 2 different view models if they are identical? (and your generating invalid html anyway). The html helpers generate the `id` attribute based on the property name, so unless you manually add an `id` attribute to the checkbox - `new { id = "createLive" }` - and use `@Html.Label("createLive", "Live")` - i.e. fake it - then its not possible

Comment: I know it's creating invalid html... that was the point of the question.
Although the view models are identical at present - conceptually they could be not identical in the future (for example if  I change the names of one the properties to liveCreate and the other to liveEdit.

Comment: You're asking for a workaround for poor design. Revisit the design here would be the best solution

Comment: Why is it a poor design?

Comment: If you really want to something like this, why not just have a parent view model containing `YourModel CreateModel { get; set; }` and `YourModel EditModel { get; set; }` so the `id` attributes will be unique - `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CreateModel.Live)` and `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.EditModel.Live)`

Comment: @Stephen - That is essentially what I have.  I then pass those view models into a partial view and above is the resulting problem.

Comment: Its only a problem if you pass the child object to the partial. Pass the model so the `name` and `id` attributes are prefixed with the property name.

Comment: That seems to have done it - Thanks Stephen.  I think it's a shame Microsoft haven't left us a correct method of overriding the id/name in some fashion with these HTML helpers.  I'm fairly sure this isn't the only use case for it.

Comment: There is a very good reason for not overriding `name` attributes (binding would fail) but as @jumpingcode pointed out, you have a poor design and you should rethink what your doing.

Comment: No one has pointed out why this is poor design.  The binding would also only fail if the override was not used automatically by other helpers etc.